# Identify value of a parent checkbox element (regardless of if it's been selected)

Tags: jquery, checkbox, nested, return-value, parent

How can I identify the value of a parent checkbox element regardless of if it's been selected?

I'm using jQuery's Nested Menu with checkboxes to create a series of nested pseudo-Select elements. If the user selects a checkbox in the nested menu I want to display their selection together with the value of the associated checkbox in the parent menu (i.e. if the user selects *`name="bother_shoulders" value="Too_small"`*, the text displayed should be 'Shoulders' *(the parent value)* + 'Too_small' *(the selected value)*).

The first line in the function below identifies the value of the element selected, but I don't know how to create a similar function which would identify the value of the unselected parent element.

JS

```
$(".dropdown_container ul li a").click(function () {
    var text = $(this).find("input").val();
    var currentHtml = $(".dropdown_box span").html();
    $(".dropdown_box span").html(currentHtml.replace(currentHtml, ''));
    $(".dropdown_box span").append(text);
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown_box"><span>1st Priority</span></div>
<div class="dropdown_container">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><label><input type="checkbox" name="first_dislike" value="Shoulders" />Shoulders</label></a>
    <ul>               
        <li><a href="#"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bother_shoulders" value="Too_small" class="goal-increase"/>Too Small</label></a></li>                
        <li><a href="#"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bother_shoulders" value="Too_big" class="goal-decrease"/>Too Big</label></a></li>
    </ul>  
    </li>  
    <li><a href="#"><label><input type="checkbox" name="first_dislike" value="Waist" />Waist</label></a>
    <ul>               
        <li><a href="#"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bother_waist" value="Too_defined" class="goal-increase"/>Too Defined</label></a></li>                
        <li><a href="#"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bother_waist" value="Not_defined" class="goal-decrease"/>Not Defined</label></a></li>
    </ul>  
    </li> 
    <!-- More List Items with Nested Menu Items --!>
</ul>
</div>
```

---

**Update -**

It's almost working :-) I've gotten two really great solutions *(thanks to @Madbreaks and @Samuel Liew)* for identifying the proper values when either a parent or child element is checked, but I'm still having a problem with the final part of the function - removing those values when an item is unchecked.

**@Madbreaks' solution** added classes to the parent `<li>` and child `<ul>` elements *(parent `class="dislike"` and child `class="reason"`)*

```
$(".dropdown_container ul li.dislike a").click(function () {
    var dislike = $(this).find("input").val();
    var dislike_formatted = dislike.replace(/_/g, " ");
    var currentHtml = $(".dropdown_box span").html();
    $(".dropdown_box span").html(currentHtml.replace(currentHtml, ''));
    $(".dropdown_box span").append(dislike_formatted);
});
$("ul.reason a").click(function () {
    var reason = $(this).find("input").val();
    var dislike = $(this).parents('li.dislike').find("input").val();
    var reason_formatted = reason.replace(/_/g, " ");
    var dislike_formatted = dislike.replace(/_/g, " ");
    var currentHtml = $(".dropdown_box span").html();
    $(".dropdown_box span").html(currentHtml.replace(currentHtml, ''));
    $(".dropdown_box span").append(dislike_formatted + ': ' + reason_formatted);
});
```

A working fiddle is posted here: [jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/Ejqp9](http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/Ejqp9)

**@Samuel Liew's solution** replaced `var currentHtml = $(".dropdown_box span").html();` with:

```
var currentHtml = '';
var $parent = $(this).parent().parents('li');
if($parent[0]) {
    var text2 = $parent.find("input").val();
    currentHtml = text2 + ': ' + currentHtml;
}
```

A working fiddle is posted here: [jsfiddle.net/samliew/H3n6m/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/H3n6m/11/)

Comment: 'parent checkbox' makes no sense, as checkbox inputs cannot have child nodes. Also, your `</label>` closing tag for `Waist` is in the wrong place.  Also, `<label>` elements require a `for` attribute.  I'd suggesting running your HTML through a validator.

Comment: @Madbreaks: I've actually just discovered that labels seem to work just fine without a 'for' attribute if they wrap everything, but thanks for catching the typo on the </label> :-)

Comment: It will work some extent, but you're not using it *correctly*.  If that matters to you, then you'd do something like: `<label for="first_dislike">Shoulders</label><input id="first_dislike" ...>`.  The label's `for` attribute references the `id` of the element is meant to label.  By doing this, users may click the label to affect the state of the checkbox.

Comment: @Madbreaks: That's what I thought :-) But another SO user told me yesterday that "you can wrap a label around an input in HTML. Then you leave out the for attribute". It seems to work just fine that way, and definitely saves time :-) On a separate note, I wanted to ask how you added the formatting to your comments (since the usual SO formatting options aren't available for comments)?

Comment: Sure, but as I said, may work but it's syntactically incorrect.  If you try running your code through a validation service it will tell you as much.  I care about that, but not everyone does.  :)  Still...writing valid code is an excellent habit to develop.  I noticed you haven't accepted any answers yet, still working on this?

Comment: @Madbreaks: That's probably a good habit to develop :-) I'm assuming that you haven't seen my comment below ;-) I think I've almost solved this problem with your help :-)

Comment: I'm happy to help, however I suggest you close/accept this question and create a new one for your "other problem".  SO questions are supposed to be a single, answerable question and not an ongoing code-fixing back and forth.  You can read more about that in the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Madbreaks: I guess I hadn't thought about this a separate question because it's a question about integrating either possible solution (I have the same challenge with Samuel's solution) in a way that I can still maintain the original functionality. I'd be happy to post a separate question if you think I should, but I've always found it a somewhat tricky posting questions with 2 sets of code (since I'm assuming that I should also post the original code)

Comment: You asked a fairly concise question in your title, and in the first line of your question body.  Perfect!  If you're having trouble with other areas of your code it's appropriate to ask separate question(s) to get help.

Comment: That, or update your original question with what your code looks like after you've modified it, then add at the bottom of it something like "Update: almost working, but still having a problem with...".  I still think a separate question is appropriate.

Comment: @Madbreaks: I took your advice and updated the question :-D BTW - Thanks for your compliment on my original question :-) It's been a real learning process figuring how to draft questions on SO (especially for a non-pro like myself), and while members can sometimes be quick with negative feedback, you're the 1rst person to give me feedback that helps me know what I'm doing right :-D

Answer (score 1):

Inside your click handler, do:

```
var parentVal = $(this).parents('li').eq(1).find('input').val();
```

This searches up the DOM hierarchy for ancestors of the clicked element, with node type `li`.  It then says "give me the 2nd furthest element", then locates the input inside it.  As I said in my comment, I'd suggest [validating your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/).  I'd also suggest indenting it properly as it can help make solutions to problems like these more apparent.

**EDIT**

My suggestion would be to add some `class` attributes to your elements.  This makes solving these types of problems almost trivial.  For example (with properly indented code) --

```
<div class="dropdown_box"><span>1st Priority</span></div>
<div class="dropdown_container">
    <ul>
        <li class="dislike">
            <a href="#"><label><input type="checkbox" name="first_dislike" value="Shoulders" />Shoulders</label></a>
            <ul class="reason">               
                <li><a href="#"><label><input class="area" type="checkbox" name="bother_shoulders" value="Too_small" class="goal-increase"/>Too Small</label></a></li>                
                <li><a href="#"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bother_shoulders" value="Too_big" class="goal-decrease"/>Too Big</label></a></li>
            </ul>  
        </li>  
        <li class="dislike">
            <a href="#"><label><input type="checkbox" name="first_dislike" value="Waist" />Waist</label></a>
            <ul class="reason">               
                <li><a href="#"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bother_waist" value="Too_defined" class="goal-increase"/>Too Defined</label></a></li>                
                <li><a href="#"><label><input type="checkbox" name="bother_waist" value="Not_defined" class="goal-decrease"/>Not Defined</label></a></li>
            </ul>  
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note the `class="dislike"` and `class="reason"` attributes.  Now you can scope your click handlers and reference other nodes much more easily.  My first example above:

```
$('ul.reason a').on('click', function(){
    // The sublist item was clicked, do something with the value:
    var reason  = $('input', this).val(),
        dislike = $(this).parents('li.dislike').find('.goal-increase').val();

    // Do something with the values...
});
```

Now do something similar, a click handler for the `<a>` that wraps the `.goal-increase` checkboxes.

Many ways to go about this, but hopefully you can see how this is helpful.

Cheers

Comment: I'd love to use this because it's nice and simple but there are 2 problems -  the function stopped working if the parent element is selected, and it's no longer removing values if an item is unchecked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, your question was, *"How can I identify the value of a parent checkbox element regardless of if it's been selected?"*.  That's what this is meant to answer.  If you felt I've been helpful, please consider up-voting my answer.

Comment: I like your idea of using classes, it just took me a little while to figure out how to integrate it with the rest of the code. But I'm still having a problem with it not removing the values when an item is unchecked :-( Would you mind taking a look at this fiddle and helping me fix that final issue? http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/Ejqp9/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".dropdown_container ul li a").click(function () {
    var text = $(this).find("input").val();
    var currentHtml = ''; // reset display text

    var $parent = $(this).parent().parents('li');
    // if parent list item exists
    if($parent[0]) {
        // search for the text box
        var text2 = $parent.find("input").val();
        currentHtml = text2 + ': ' + currentHtml;
    }
    $(".dropdown_box span").html(currentHtml);
    $(".dropdown_box span").append(text);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/H3n6m/11/

Comment: A big chunk of code with no explanation of what it's doing is rarely a good answer. No offense.

Comment: This is great because it works for both the parent and child elements, but the function is no longer removing the values if an item is unchecked. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that :-( Would you be able to show me what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If what you're after is the checking that is in the `<li>` that is right before the `<ul>` of the current checkbox, then you can get that like this:

```
$(".dropdown_container ul ul li a").click(function () {
    var checkboxVal = $(this).closest("ul").prev("li")
                        .find("input:checkbox").val();
});
```

This gets the parent `<ul>`, then gets the `<li>` before it, then finds the checkbox in that `<li>`, then gets the value of that checkbox.

Comment: @ChayaCooper - This is the entire event handler for a submenu click.  It does exactly what my answer describes.  If you want something different, then you will have to describe in more detail what you want it to do (your question is not particularly clear in this regard).

Comment: How would I integrate it into the rest of my function?